# URI#getQuery() fails to decode illegal characters

Tags: java

Why

```
new URI(
    null,
    null,
    "/monitor/123456/data",
    "filterParams=[{\"id\":12,\"type\":\"dimension\"}]",
    null).getQuery()
```

returns

> filterParams=[%7B%22id%22:12,%22type%22:%22dimension%22%7D]

and not

> "filterParams=[{\"id\":12,\"type\":\"dimension\"}]"

According to `URI#getQuery()` documentation

> The string returned by this method is equal to that returned by the `#getRawQuery()` method except that all sequences of escaped octets are decoded.

Is it JDK bug or I am missing some understanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the comment above the private method URI.decode it is not a bug but a feature :).

```
/*
Evaluates all escapes in s, applying UTF-8 decoding if needed.  Assumes
that escapes are well-formed syntactically, i.e., of the form %XX.  If a
sequence of escaped octets is not valid UTF-8 then the erroneous octets
are replaced with '\uFFFD'.
Exception: any "%" found between "[]" is left alone. It is an IPv6  literal with a scope_id
*/
private static String decode(String s) {...}
```